# Queue function calls to write char for char

Tags: c#

**What should it do**

I'm trying to write some text char for char into a `TextBlock`. I'm using this code for this:

```
void WriteTextCharForChar(String text)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        foreach(Char c in text)
        {
            TxtDisplayAppendText(c.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(20, 100));
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }).Start();
}
```

**The problem**

The Problem is that the text, of course, gets mixed when calling this method more then once. What I would need is a kind of queue or wait any how until the currently text is written to the `TextBlock`. 
Of curse I'm open to any other solution to get this working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are several options here.

1. You could add a `lock` around the work that the thread does, so that there is never more than one running at a time.

   This has several problems though:

   1. The items aren't necessarily processed in order
   2. You're creating lots of threads, all of which are spending almost all of their time waiting; this is very wasteful of resources.
2. You could create a thread safe queue (`BlockingCollection` would be best) and then have a single thread reading from it and writing out the results while the UI thread just adds to the queue

   This also has problems.  Most notably you're creating a new thread that's going to be spending basically all of its time waiting around.  This is probably better than #1, but not by a lot.
3. You could avoid using multiple threads entirely and do everything asynchronously.  The Task Parallel Library gives you a lot of tools to help with this.  This is the best option as it results in the creation of 0 extra threads.

So first we'll create a helper method that will handling the writing of the text itself, so that another thread can be the one to handle "scheduling" these calls.  This method will be much easier to write using `await`.  A key point to note is that, rather than blocking the current thread for an unknown period of time, it will use `Task.Delay` to continue execution at a point in the future without blocking the thread:

```
private async Task WriteText(string text)
{
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        TxtDisplayAppendText(c.ToString());
        await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(20, 100));
    }
}
```

Now for your method.  We can manage our queue though what will be in effect a linked list of tasks.  If we have a single field of type `Task` representing the "previous task" we can have each method call add a continuation to that task, and then set itself as the previous task.  The next task will set itself as the continuation of that, and so on.  Each continuation will fire when the previous task runs, or will run immediately if the previous task has already finished, so this gives us our "queue", effectively.  Note that since `WriteTextCharForChar` is being called from the UI thread these calls are all already synchronized, so there's no need to `lock` around the manipulation of this task.

```
private Task previousWrite = Task.FromResult(false); //already completed task
private void WriteTextCharForChar(String text)
{
    previousWrite = previousWrite.ContinueWith(t => WriteText(text))
        .Unwrap();
}
```